# Change Background color or particular cell containing image in kendo grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have added columns dynamically in kendo grid. The first column in the grid is displaying image for each row. I have added on change event for the selected row. On click of the row I have added css to display the selected row as Gray color.

But the first column that displays the image doesn't display in Gray entirely when the row is selected.

The part of image background is displayed in white and not gray.

This is how I have added the image in the grid column.

```
 TitleArray.push({ template: "<img src='/Images/Icon.PNG'></img>", width: 35 })
```

I have added the attachment that displays the image issue [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ZkuB.png).

The selected row is displayed as Gray. But the image column is displaying a white region around the image and I don't want it like that. It should entirely display in the Gray color.

I want the entire background to display in Gray.

Please tell how can I do this.

Comment: You should be able to use dev tools in your browser to see exactly what css is being applied to the elements

Comment: Are you sure that the background of your image is transparent?

Comment: Thanks to all your help. Yes, I got that working. I think something in CSS was missing. Changed the image and got that working. Thanks